# How do I replace word in string except first occurrence using c#

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

How do I replace word in string except first occurrence using c#

for example

```
string s= "hello my name is hello my name hello";
```

replace `hello` with `x`

```
output should be string news = "hello my name is x my name x";
```

I tried like works fine

```
string originalStr = "hello my hello ditch hello";
        string temp = "hello";
        string str = originalStr.Substring(0, originalStr.IndexOf(temp) + temp.Length);
        originalStr = str + originalStr.Substring(str.Length).Replace(temp, "x");
```

can I have Regex expression for above code ?

Comment: It should be first occurrence or word without space?

Comment: Is this poor sample data or poor exlanation? The first word is not "llo" so why should it be replaced at all? Or don't want you to replace complete words but also substrings?

Comment: updated quaetion with clear data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it for a general pattern:

```
var matchPattern = Regex.Escape("llo");
var replacePattern = string.Format("(?<={0}.*){0}", matchPattern);
var regex = new Regex(replacePattern);
var newText = regex.Replace("hello llo llo", "x");
```

If you want to only match and replace whole words, edit your pattern accordingly:

```
var matchPattern = @"\b" + Regex.Escape("hello") + @"\b";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string pat = "hello";
string tgt = "x";
string tmp = s.Substring(s.IndexOf(pat)+pat.Length);
s = s.Replace(tmp, tmp.Replace(pat,tgt));
```

`tmp` is the substring of the original string starting after the end of first occurrence of the pattern to be replaced (`pat`). We then replace `pat` with the desired value (`tgt`) within this substring, and replace the substring in the original string with this updated value.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/WKRJZM7865)

Comment: This won't work in all cases. Try with this input string: `string s= " my hello my hello my hello my hello my hello my hello my hello my";`

Comment: My code is also working perfect in above condition :)

Comment: @ashish Feel free to use my code if your input is guaranteed to be like the sample. But Lasse has pointed out a failed case, and you need to understand that it must also be handled correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need regex? You could use this little LINQ query and `String.Join`:

```
int wordCount = 0;
var newWords = s.Split()
    .Select(word => word != "hello" || ++wordCount == 1 ? word : "x");
string newText = string.Join(" ", newWords);
```

But note that this will replace all white-spaces (even tabs or newlines) with a space.